# asp:Image control showing empty placeholder when ImageUrl = string.Empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have an `<asp:Image>` control on my `.aspx` page. I have a function which programatically removes the image from the control by setting: `myImage.ImageUrl = string.Empty`. Problem is, after this procedure I am left with an empty placeholder:

[image]

How can I get rid of that placeholder?

Comment: `myImage.Visible = false;`

Answer (score 1):

To hide a control, set the property `Visibile` to `false`. This causes it not not be rendered at all, removing the tag completely from the resulting HTML.